# Request object is not passed to static method using OGNL in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, scriptlet

I am developing a Struts 2.3 application. In that application I am calling a static utility method from JSP which takes `HttpServletRequest` object as argument and returns a string after processing request. When I tried using JSP scriptlet, method got invoked with proper argument like:

```
<%
    String resultStr = com.testapp.util.Utility.getResult(request);
%>
```

But when I tried to use the OGNL for the same logic, method got invoked with null request object as argument instead of actual request object like:

```
<s:set name="resultStr" var="resultStr"
       value="@com.testapp.util.Utility@getResult(request)" />
```

I also tried `#request` instead of `request` in OGNL but in that case method didn't get invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this constant in the configuration file to enable static method access.

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />
```

Use

```
<s:set name="resultStr" var="resultStr" value="@com.testapp.util.Utility@getResult()" />
```

and in the `getResult() {`

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

Comment: It is already configured. As I mentioned, I am able to invoke static method using OGNL but I am not get passed `request` object in method. It is null.

Comment: You  don't need it use `ServletActionContext.getRequest()`

Comment: I tried `HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();` instead of passing `request` object and it worked :) Thanks for your quick help !! But I am still not able to understand that why `request` object was not passed as argument.

Comment: You cannot access scripting variables inside the struts tags.